# using nagelfar tool to get code coverage in Tcl

Tags: tcl, code-coverage

I am using nagelfar tool to get code coverage of a Tcl code (which bundled into a executable (its exe on Windows and bin on Linux) using starkit and tclkit). I instrumented the Tcl code and build an executable using starkit and tclkit. When I run this binary it works properly but i dont get the `filename_log` file that nagelfar generates.

Can somebody tell how do i get that log file?

Answer (score 1):

The nagelfar tool have no such option , at least it is not exists in nagelfar help or in description on [project's home page](http://nagelfar.berlios.de/)

Might be you can use ***-html*** flag:

```
-html             : Generate html-output.
```

Comment: The `-html` flag was introduced for my favorite Tcl paste site http://paste.tclhelp.net/. It contains some output (e.g. expr without braces) that links to a topic on that site's forums.